# which is pelican executable script that user executes from shell?

Tags: python, executable, pelican

I am trying to call pelican via subprocess for automated blog posting, however when I tried `which pelican` in shell and opened it. I found this

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'pelican==3.5.0','console_scripts','pelican'
__requires__ = 'pelican==3.5.0'
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

sys.exit(
   load_entry_point('pelican==3.5.0', 'console_scripts', 'pelican')()
)
```

while I was expecting to see a call to main function that gets called when somebody passes argument from shell to pelican.(I am not talking about `pelican-quickstart`)

I tried to look into the pelican project I think its the `__init__.py` that has main function, but normally I would have a executable wrapper that calls this main function, so can anyone redirect me to which function the above code passes the argument passed by user ?

Comment: These wrappers are generated by easy_install as you'd expect. However, it's an implementation detail -- why do you need to know this to invoke it via the `subprocess` module? This is information that would be more relevant if you wanted to call the `main()` function *directly*, _without_ going through the wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [pelican's `setup.py`](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/blob/master/setup.py):

```
entry_points = {
    'console_scripts': [
        'pelican = pelican:main',
        'pelican-import = pelican.tools.pelican_import:main',
        'pelican-quickstart = pelican.tools.pelican_quickstart:main',
        'pelican-themes = pelican.tools.pelican_themes:main'
    ]
}
```

Thus, the entry point for the `pelican` command is the `main()` function in the `pelican` module; you could also reach it by `import pelican; pelican.main()`. (Similarly, for `pelican-quickstart`: `import pelican.tools.pelican_quickstart; pelican.tools.pelican_quickstart.main()`).

To find the file:

```
import pelican
print pelican.__file__
```

...or, to get a handle on the `main` function directly:

```
>>> from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
>>> mainfunc = load_entry_point('pelican', 'console_scripts', 'pelican')
>>> print mainfunc.__module__
'pelican'
>>> mainfunc()
WARNING: Feeds generated without SITEURL set properly may not be valid
```